# Running an app with multicores on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, multiprocessing

I am running an app on ubuntu like the following:

```
"oni2avi --depth-peng=yes Captured.oni output.avi"
```

The computer has 47 cores. How can I run this app by using 47 cores without making a change on the code?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run a program on many cores, write a simple loop to start up multiple copies of the program.

The next example runs a program which outputs a number, waits one second, then exits:

## multiprocessing three commands

```
for num in {1..3} ; do (echo $num ; sleep 1 ) & done
```

## Output

```
1
2
3
```

Linux tends to put different processes on different cores. So for your example, starting the program on 47 cores:

```
for num in {1..47} ; do (echo $num ; oni2avi --depth-peng=yes Captured.oni output.avi) & done
```

However: your program won't run 47x faster; it'll the *same* work 47 times. To make your program run faster, by using multiple cores, you'll have to rewrite the program.